# Backing Up Live Site Using Akeeba

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, akeebabackup, backups

Joomla 3.9.15

I have been using Akeeba to backup my sites and it's very good.

I've recently installed in on quite a busy site, users are regularly logging in and out of the front and back end, and making content changes.

Can I simply run the Akeeba backup process as normal in the admin area, or should I take any action before this?

I'm thinking things such as logging users out of my site, or making the site temporarily unavailable? Should I allocate a certain window of time during the week for a backup and inform users not to login or make changes during this time?

Often there are a number of users logged into the admin area simultaneously, however there is only one super admin (me).

I don't know if it makes any difference that there are database changes occurring during the backup process? I'm sure the developer took this into consideration but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: For such a busy site, configure an automatic (with a cron job) database only backup every x hours and select if not 2, at least 1 3rd party cloud storage to store the sql dumps made by akeeba and do not keep the archives on your server.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a change for that some is missing if you should use a backup.
If you use the pro version of akeebabackup you can set it to run backup at night automatical. there will be less users online, i guess.

Comment: Thank you for contributing Brian.  Please take the [tour] and consider introducing yourself by editing your profile.